# SQL Case statement replacing values incorrectly

Tags: sql, syntax

I'm trying to rename the values of one column of a database I have READ-ONLY access to.  I also want to combine two of the values into one.  I'm using a SQL CASE query, but it is converting values incorrectly.  Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT
DATE(appraisal.created_time),
appraisal_steps.title,
Count(appraisal.appraisal_id),
case appraisal_steps.title
 when "archive" then "A_Archived"
 when "on_sale" then "J_Selling"
 when "under_evaluation" then "F_Evaluating"
 when "evaluated" then "H_Appraisal Complete"
 when "pending" then "B_Pending"
 when "crap" then "C_Not For Lofty"
 when "waiting_internal_expert_evaluation" then "D_Unclaimed"
 when ("expert_needs_information" OR "admin_needs_information") then "E_Waiting"
 when "seller_answered_to_expert_question" then "G_Needs_Attn"
 when "ready_to_be_sold" then "I_Ready"
 else "wtf"
end as Status

FROM
appraisal
INNER JOIN appraisal_steps ON appraisal.`status` = appraisal_steps.step_id
WHERE
appraisal.powersale = 0
GROUP BY
DATE(appraisal.created_time),
appraisal_steps.title
ORDER BY
appraisal_steps.title DESC, status
```

The result is correct for some of the status (is the plural stati? :) but seller_answered_to_expert_question is converted to "E_Waiting", which is incorrect.

If I change the order of the "When" clauses, different stati work and don't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What flavour of sql? Also, in English, the plural is statuses - I don't know about latin, but we don't usually speak it on stackoverflow ;)

Comment: I would say that the plural of 'status' is 'statuses', but that doesn't affect your SQL.  What happens if you split the OR clause into two separate WHEN clauses?  I expect it to work.  What does 'ready_to_be_sold' map to?  Does anything map to 'wtf'?  I think that what's happening is that appraisal_steps.title is being compared with `("E" OR "A")` as `appraisal_steps.title = ("E" OR "A")` and this is giving TRUE (so, I expect ready to be sold to map to `E_waiting` and also any invalid code in `appraisal_steps.title`.

Comment: Guessing MySQL, all other RDBMS I tested can't even handle the `OR` in your `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a `CASE` statement formatted like `CASE field WHEN criteria THEN END` doesn't allow for multiple criteria via `OR` or `AND` so the second criteria in that `WHEN` line isn't being compared to the value in your title field, nothing is getting bucketed in "G_Needs_Attn", "I_Ready", or "wtf" in this case.

You can fix this in a couple ways:

split your `OR` line into two:

```
 when "expert_needs_information" then "E_Waiting"
 when "admin_needs_information" then "E_Waiting"
```

Or use this format of `CASE` statement:

```
    SELECT
    DATE(appraisal.created_time),
    appraisal_steps.title,
    Count(appraisal.appraisal_id),
    case when appraisal_steps.title = "archive" then "A_Archived"
     when appraisal_steps.title = "on_sale" then "J_Selling"
     when appraisal_steps.title = "under_evaluation" then "F_Evaluating"
     when appraisal_steps.title = "evaluated" then "H_Appraisal Complete"
     when appraisal_steps.title = "pending" then "B_Pending"
     when appraisal_steps.title = "crap" then "C_Not For Lofty"
     when appraisal_steps.title = "waiting_internal_expert_evaluation" then "D_Unclaimed"
     when appraisal_steps.title = "expert_needs_information" OR appraisal_steps.title = "admin_needs_information" then "E_Waiting"
     when appraisal_steps.title = "seller_answered_to_expert_question" then "G_Needs_Attn"
     when appraisal_steps.title = "ready_to_be_sold" then "I_Ready"
     else "wtf"
    end as Status       
    FROM
    appraisal
    INNER JOIN appraisal_steps ON appraisal.`status` = appraisal_steps.step_id
    WHERE
    appraisal.powersale = 0
    GROUP BY
    DATE(appraisal.created_time),
    appraisal_steps.title
    ORDER BY
    appraisal_steps.title DESC, status
```

This format allows for criteria on multiple fields to be evaluated, or multiple criteria for the same field.  You could also use `when appraisal_steps.title IN ("expert_needs_information","admin_needs_information") then "E_Waiting"` for that line.

Here's a demo showing how the errant `OR` ends up as a catch-all: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d93ad/1/0)

Comment: That's the elaborated version what I said in my comment.  Thanks for saving me typing it up.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, Goat CO and Jonathan Leffler!  This worked and I appreciate it a lot!